# Getting the color of all the pixels of screen

Tags: ios, for-loop, pixel

I know how can we get the color of any pixel. and for that I am using ColorOfPoint method

```
- (UIColor *) colorOfPoint:(CGPoint)point
{
    unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask & kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);

    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);


    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithRed:pixel[0]/255.0 green:pixel[1]/255.0 blue:pixel[2]/255.0 alpha:pixel[3]/255.0];

    return color;
}
```

Now I can call this method when I want to any pixel color. What if I want to know the color of all the pixels of screen. I think I will have to write 2 for loops

```
for (int x_axis=0; x_axis<screenWidth/2; x_axis++)
{
    for (int y_axis=0; y_axis<screenHeight/2; y_axis++)
    {
    }
}
```

and I can call this function in this for loop. Now, I want to return true if the pixel color is red else it should continue checking rest of pixels of screen.

I have implemented this way, but it freezes and slow down the app. Don't know if there's any other way to loop through all the pixels of screen.

Please help!

Comment: how about getting the screen shot of the view in image and finding your required colour in those?

Comment: @Hanuman Please can you explain more in detail

Comment: if your are not looking to render the screen dynamically, you have a option to create a image from the current view and then write your logic across that

Answer (score 0):

OMG,

you render the whole screen just to get the color of one pixel, right? So if you have 156000 pixels you render the screen 156000 times. This can only be really really slow. You should render the screen only once!

Comment: Please advice what other way can I do

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the loop once while you create the colorspace. See the updated code:

```
- (BOOL) isRedPresent
{
    CGPoint point;
    unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4,
           colorSpace,  kCGBitmapAlphaInfoMask & kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    BOOL isRed = FALSE;
    for (int x_axis=0; x_axis<screenWidth/2; x_axis++)
    {
         for (int y_axis=0; y_axis<screenHeight/2; y_axis++)
         {
                CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -x_axis, -y_axis);
                [self.layer renderInContext:context];
                if(pixel[0] == 255 && pixel[1] == 0 && pixel[2] == 0)
                {
                       isRed = TRUE;
                       break;
                }
          }
    } 

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    return isRed;
}
```

Comment: Its still slowing down the app

Comment: If I run in background thread, I won't be able to return any value by the time though.